# Error occured due to SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: Users but added the model into sequelize-typescript

Tags: typescript, express, sqlite, dependency-injection, sequelize-typescript

Thanks for looking at my question. I'm trying to understand and implement "sequelize-typescript" library into my Express.JS REST API which I developed it using Dependency Injection style. But I've been encountering an issue which is this error:

Error occured due to SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: Users

Here's my code for my entity called "user.ts":

```
export class User extends Model {
@PrimaryKey
@Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true
})
declare userId: number

@Column({
    type: DataType.STRING
})
declare firstName : string;

@Column({
    type: DataType.STRING
})
declare lastName: string;

@Column({
    type: DataType.STRING
})
declare email: string;

@Column({
    type: DataType.STRING
})
declare phone: string;}
```

My database which I've created as a middleware:

```
export default class DatabaseMiddleware {
private databaseInstance : Sequelize;

constructor() {
    this.databaseInstance = new Sequelize({
        database: process.env.MAMLAKHA_DATABASE_NAME,
        dialect: "sqlite",
        host: process.env.MAMLAKHA_DATABASE_HOST,
        username: process.env.MAMLAKHA_DATABASE_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.MAMLAKHA_DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        // storage: process.env.MAMLAKHA_DATABASE_STORAGE_PATH,
        logging(sql, timing) {
            console.log("The SQL statement from Sequelize executed is", sql, timing);
        },
        models: [User],
        repositoryMode: true
    });
}

public async connectToDatabase() {
    try {
        await this.databaseInstance.authenticate();
        if(process.env.ENVIRONMENT_PROFILE === "development") {
            await this.databaseInstance.sync({ alter: true });
        }

        console.log("Connection to database has been established successfully");
    } catch(error) {
        console.error("Unable to connect to database due to", error);
    }
}

public getDatabaseInstance() {
    return this.databaseInstance;
}}
```

Finally, here's the main code where the whole REST API starts:

```
class App {
private baseDirectory : string;
private expressApp : Express

// Middleware Instances
private databaseMiddleware : DatabaseMiddleware;

constructor() {
    dotenv.config({ path: "./.env.development" });
    this.baseDirectory = __dirname;
    this.expressApp = express();
    routingContainer(Container);

    useExpressServer(this.expressApp, {
        routePrefix: process.env.MAMLAKHA_ROUTE_PREFIX,
        defaultErrorHandler: false,
        controllers: [this.baseDirectory + `/**/controllers/*.ts`]
    });

    this.expressApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    this.expressApp.use(bodyParser.json());

    this.databaseMiddleware = new DatabaseMiddleware();
}

run() {
    this.expressApp.listen(process.env.MAMLAKHA_REST_API_PORT, () => {
        console.info(`Hello there, it's Mamlakha app and it's running on port ${process.env.MAMLAKHA_REST_API_PORT} `);
    });

    this.databaseMiddleware.connectToDatabase();
}

get expressAppInstance() : Express {
    return this.expressApp;
} } const main : App = new App(); main.run();
```

I've tried following the documentation in GitHub for this library but I can't make it work and hence the error. Please share your solutions if you have encountered this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking into the question and to @RobertRendell for giving me a solution. There are 2 solutions that I found resolving my error. One of them is @RobertRendell's answer which creates the table first before running your application.

Another solution is to have this `sync({ alter: true, force: true });` on your Sequelize instance. The flag called `force: true` will create the table based on your data model if doesn't exists in your database.

Once again thanks to @RobertRendell for his solution and hope my answer to my predicament will able to solve yours.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this seems like a problem with your understanding of Sequelize.

Have you created a migration and run it against the database instance?

Create a migration using the sequelize CLI:
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#creating-the-first-model-and-migration

Run the migration using the sequelize CLI:
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#running-migrations

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer. I've worked with Sequelize before but without using migration to create table and seed data. However, I will try to install Sequelize and try migration and let you know the status

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the answer. However, your answer didn't worked as expected. I was able to create the migration and seed the initial data but when calling the API to add data via the "sequelize-typescript" repository mode, it doesn't add the data and instead comes with the same error "Error occured due to SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: Users".

Comment: Hi Robert, by right the "sequelize-typescript" instance has the "models" attributes which takes in the models which are extended to "Model". Wouldn't it create the tables instantly after connecting to the database? Based on my experience, it had created it before

Comment: Based on your "User" model code, I would have expected that to have generated a migration that creates a database table "User". Can you confirm that is the case? Can you physically see that table in the db browser? Note that the error message has "Users" vs "User" which may indicate a mismatch

Comment: No. I would not expect sequelize to make any structural changes to the database without executing a migration. That includes creating a table that wasn't there before.

Comment: Hi Robert, I was able to run the migrations and was able to create a table and after which no error was appearing any longer. One thing I also found is that, without migration you can pass a flag to the `sync({ force: true})` to make the table be created during the application although I would use this approach for development only.